# How to select the latest date & time for each row in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

**Df1**

```
2017-01-27 01

2017-01-26 03

2017-01-27 15

2017-04-03 02
```

**Df2**

```
2017-01-26 03

2017-01-27 00

2017-01-27 15

2017-04-03 18
```

**Latest**

```
2017-01-27 01

2017-01-27 00

2017-01-27 15

2017-04-03 18
```

Comment: `pmax(Df1, Df2)`

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apply(data.frame(a=c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01", "2017-01-01"),
             b=c("2016-02-01","2016-01-01", "2016-12-01")), 1, max)
```

This should give you the newest date per line